# Can a US Citizen drive in California with a foreign Driver's License? If currently a resident in CA but moved recently?

Tags: legal, driving, regulations, driving-licenses

Can a US Citizen with a foreign Driver's License drive in California? If they recently moved to the USA and is currently a resident of California?

Comment: did you find out what happens given that it is impossible to get a DMV appointment for months?

Answer (score 4):

Your citizenship is not relevant; what matters is whether you are a resident of California. [Adult nonresidents](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/hdbk/ca_dl#adultsvisiting) temporarily in California can drive with their foreign or out-of-state driver's license (from their place of residence) without limit.

> Visitors over 18 years old with a valid DL from their home state or
>   country may drive in California without getting a California DL as
>   long as their home state or country DL is valid.

However, residents of California can drive with a foreign or out-of-state driver's license for no more than 10 days after [becoming a resident of California](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/hdbk/ca_dl#newresidents).

> When you become a California resident and you want to drive in
>   California, you must apply for a California DL within 10 days.